# How to know if a function is finished?

Tags: objective-c, timer

I'm using

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(myfunc:) userInfo:text repeats:false];
```

in my code. How can I know if `myfunc` has finished running so that I can fetch the global variables it has changed?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't the function notify the recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can notify the caller via Cocoa's [notification system](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043-SW1).